# How can I use AMPscript to show HTML button based on an ID being passed?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

Here is what I have so far:

```
%%[ IF @ClinicID == 33
THEN                                                      
Show HTML button
ELSE
Show Nothing
ENDIF ]%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it like this.  You don't need a show nothing ELSE case:

```
%%[IF @ClinicID == 33 THEN ]%% <some> html button goes here </some> %%[ENDIF]%%
```

Just put the HTML in between CLOSED ampscript.  You can add ELSEIF and ELSE the same way:

```
%%[IF @ClinicID == 33 THEN ]%% <some> html button goes here </some> 
%%[ELSEIF @ClinicID == 35 THEN ]%% <someother> html button goes here </someother> 
%%[ELSE]%% <somedefault> html button goes here </somedefault> 
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I use the first suggested line of code the block does not execute. I set up a test data extension to make sure the ClinicID was always 33. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you setting @ClinicID to be 33?  Unless there is a SET call somewhere, its going to be something else.  Please feel free to post the entirety of your ampscript and we'll have a look.

Comment: %%[VAR <at symbol>ClinicID  
SET <at symbol>ClinicID = ClinicID  
%%[IF <at symbol>ClinicID == 33 THEN]%%  
<some><p><img/link></some>  
%%[ENDIF]%%  
]%%

Comment: Every %%[ has to have a matching ]%%, and I'm not sure yours lines up correctly.  Using you stuff, I would write


%%[VAR <at symbol>ClinicID SET <at symbol>ClinicID = ClinicID ]%% %%[IF <at symbol>ClinicID == 33 THEN]%% <some><p><img/link></some> %%[ENDIF]%%

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be working now. If I want to use more than one ID can I use "IN (...)" or does it need to be a OR scenario?

Comment: Needs to be OR.  AND operators are also legal, just FYI.

AMPscript syntax guide: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/